# how to write '&amp' in html without converting to '&'?

Tags: html

I need to ignore the character escaping and actually write &amp in my text.

Is there a way to escape the escape?

Comment: I presume you mean `&amp;` (with semicolon). You don't have to ignore escaping, you have to use escaping: `&amp;amp;`.

Comment: well you know how to produce an & so just append amp; afterwards

Comment: Side note: this question must have been answered here a dozen times but I'm totally unable to find a proper duplicate to link :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use &ampamp for writing &amp

Comment: Beware that both the question and this answer are missing the trailing semicolon: "An HTML entity is a piece of text ("string") that begins with an ampersand (&) and ends with a semicolon (;)." ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity))